# How to pass GridView row to TemplateField function?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a GridView that has 3 columns: FirstName, LastName and a TemplateField FullName where I string together FirstName and LastName.

Assuming calling DisplayFullName is the function I want to use to concatenate FirstName and LastName, **how do I pass the row argument to the function and how to declare the parameter of the function?** Thanks.

Here's my code for the FullName column:

> ```
>         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FullName">
>             <ItemTemplate>
>                 <%# DisplayFullName(???) %>
>             </ItemTemplate>
>         </asp:TemplateField>
> ```

Here's my declaration for the function:

> ```
> protected string DisplayFullName(???)
>   { ... }
> ```

The ??? are where I need help. OR do I need to pass the row at all? If each time DisplayFullName is called, the 'current' row is known. If so, how do I access the current row in DisplayFullName?

**I simplified the operation for the sake of clarity of the question. In reality, there can be up to 20 values in the row I need and I want to do some calculations in the function called.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@RJIGO: You can use function like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
     <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DisplayFullName(Eval("FirstName"), Eval("LastName"))%>         
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

and your code behind method will like this

```
  protected string DisplayFullName(object FirstName, object LastName)
  {
      return Convert.ToString(FirstName)+Convert.ToString(LastName);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Had to post since nobody seemed to give you an answer that does exactly what you ask for - passing the row to a backend function.

Simply pass "Container.DataItem" to your function - this is the DataRow

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <%# DisplayFullName(Container.DataItem) %>
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

then in the CodeBehind you can manipulate it as a DataRowView:

```
public string DisplayFullName(object containerDataItem)
{
    string firstName = ((DataRowView)containerDataItem)["FirstName"].ToString();
    string lastName = ((DataRowView)containerDataItem)["LastName"].ToString();
    ...
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! The answer for what exactly is asked for!

Comment: Finally somebody answered the question that was actually asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are calling a function here to display full name.
You can use like this in your code to achieve full name:

```
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Eval("FirstName") %>&nbsp;<%#Eval("LastName") %>   
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I added a clarification in my question. The scenario is more complicated. In reality, I need to do some calculations for the TemplateField.

Comment: <%# FunctionName(parameter1, parameter2, ..., parameterN) %> call your function like this. the parameter may be your rowid or firstname, last name anything.

Comment: This is not what I want to do. Because all the arguments are contained in the row. There can be up to 20 arguments. So all I should pass is the row then extract all the data from the row in the called function.

Comment: Then simply pass your data key in function & then get your items. Refer this.. might be help you http://forums.asp.net/t/1645113.aspx/1